# Joomla Path not in open_basedir paths

Tags: joomla, web, permissions

I'm trying to upload new plug-in into my Joomla website on remote server (`websitename.com/administrator`).
I specified permissions for all folders and subfolders using `FileZilla` (777 - read,write,etc.)
But when I go to `Extensions Manager` and try to upload the plugin from my local disc drive, I get the following error message:

```
JFolder::create: Path not in open_basedir paths
Warning: Failed to move file!
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Firstly - do NOT go putting all folders/subfolders at 777 permissions. That is a HUGE security risk. You need to leave them at their default permissions levels. Secondly - which plugin are you trying to upload? Did you create this plugin? If you're following a tutorial from somewhere and they recommended setting permissions on folders to 777, you may want to pick something else because they clearly do not know what they are talking about. It could be an old/out-of-date plugin or a plugin for the wrong version that is causing the issue? (i.e. trying to install a joomla1.5 plugin into a joomla3.

Comment: Thanks. I installed this plugin on my localhost. So it's not the problem of Joomla versions. Well, it seems that the only solution is to re-upload files from localhost to remote server.

Comment: And the plugin worked as expected on your localhost without issue?  It's just giving issues on the remote server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix the issue - often the culprit can be these two locations:

$log_path = '/home/myname/public_html/logs';

$tmp_path = '/home/myname/public_html/tmp';

in your configuration.php file.  Check that those are set to the appropriate location (and do not still say //localhost/wahtever).

Mostly the default permissions should work fine without issue.

A ridiculously easy to way to transfer from 'localhost' to hosted servers is to use [Akeeba Backup](https://www.akeebabackup.com/) - you simply make a backup of your completed site on your localhost (which can be a .zip format) upload that to your remote server, unzip, walk through the re-install process (takes under 5 minutes) and your site is up and running.

The reinstall process will automatically change 99% of the localhost stuff so you won't have issues like this going forward.